# getIntent.getSerializable() returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to send Part object with intent from one activity to another. However I still get null pointer exception. This is how I send it :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,InvActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Part",part);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and this is how I try to receive it :

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.e(TAG, "onRestart: ");

        if(getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Part") != null) {
            Part part = (Part) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Part");
            Log.e(TAG, "onRestart: "+ part.getName() );
        }
    }
```

However it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`getIntent().getExtras()` return a `Bundle` and you are inflating the `intent` without a `Bundle` directly the `Serializable` to the `Intent` you should get it directly from the `Intent`. like this:

```
if(getIntent().getSerializable("Part") != null) {
   Part part = (Part) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Part");
   Log.e(TAG, "onRestart: "+ part.getName() );
}
```

Comment: Why are you getting the data in onRestart()?

Comment: cause activity is being created earlier , I go to another activity and come back to the first one.

Comment: In this case you should use onActivityResult() to send data between yours activities.

Answer (score 2):

Once use below code where i have cast with Serializable

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,InvActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("Part", (Serializable) part);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);      



Part part;
    part = (Part) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Part");
```

## Note:

```
public class Part implements Serializable{
}
```

Comment: Once use this 
intent.putExtra("Part", (Serializable)part);

  part = (Part) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Part");

Answer (score 1):

```
if(getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Part") != null) {
        Part part = (Part) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Part");
        Log.e(TAG, "onRestart: "+ part.getName() );
    }
```

It should work like that.

Ps: You shouldn't be using this onRestart. It's probably best if you start the activity waiting for a result.